# Set up basic client server comunication

Tags: linux, networking

I am new to Linux, and I want to set up a basic client server configuration scenario like this:

```
1. I have installed two Linux OSs on virtual machine.   
    A. Server having ip=192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 and hostname=server.com  
    B. Client having ip=192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0 and hostname=client.com  
2. /etc/hosts made changes 192.168.0.1 server.com  
                           192.168.0.2 client.com at both sides  
3. On the virtual machine I selected as NAT networking for both.
```

But the question is Can the server and client ping themselves, but not each other?
What is remaining?

Comment: firewall/iptables

Answer (score 2):

As you have selected NAT as netwoking on both the instances it is not possible to ping each other.

**If you want to ping client/server you should select Bridged networking or Internal networking**

Reference https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: Why won't they ping each other ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: In NAT mode every vm thinks they are on their own isolated network. And when they send their traffic via the gateway VirtualBox/Vmware rewrites the packets to make them appear as though they originated from the Host, rather than the Guest (running inside the Host).

Comment: I selected bridged networking but still not able to ping is there any other thing that I missing?

Comment: @mangesh: Are you manually entering the IP Address in both the machines?

Comment: yes I am manually entering ip

Comment: @mangesh Don't need to put the IP address manually. In Bridged networking the vm's will get the IP address automatically. You need not to do anything on the vm's. Just start both the vm's on bridge networking and they both will ping each other as they are in the same network.

Comment: Hi Hussain thax its working